# How to adjust image's size adapt to the viewport?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm making a website which is very similar as this site: https://paris.demo.vigbo.com/

The problem I'm having now is I have no clue of how to make the slideshow image on the homepage always adapt to the screen size, **where its bottom line always attach to the bottom of the viewport.** And also, **when you resize the window, it stays the same way.**

What I've tried so far:

```
var h= $(window).innerHeight()-115;//115 is the total height of nav + headerline
$('.slides_show').height(h);
$('.slides').height(h);
```

but it doesn't work, because `$(window).innerHeight()` doesn't exclude the extra part on the top of the browser?

I also think achieve it via js is not a great idea, though I'm open to it. I hope someone can give me a solution using CSS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: read about `vh` unit

Comment: You can read about _viewport_ units, but you might also consider the _CSS_ way with the `background-image` & _co._, where `background-size: cover` does what you're looking for.

Comment: I've already sloved the issue via jquery $(window).resize event, thanks for help.